# Android Studio Profiler very laggy in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: android-studio, android-profiler

Every time when I open the profiler everything starts to lag.
My configuration : ubuntu gnome 16.04, i7 7700, 16 gb RAM, Android Studio 3.1.2